# Rails - no such file to load -- browser [gem]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running Rails 3.1.4 and included the [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser/tree/318fbd808a5f909380606c166c711182bb1d33ee) so I can alter the appearance of my site for Internet Explorer.  However, when I put:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'browser'
```

at the top of my controller, I get the message `no such file to load -- browser`.

When I run `bundle show browser' it says it's installed.  Also, I can see it installed when I look at my locally directory using Windows Explorer.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have to have `require 'browser'` to make it work.

Instead, in the application controller, I just needed to do this:

```
before_filter :current_browser

def current_browser
  @browser = Browser.new(:ua => request.user_agent)
end
```